# Are downvote costs visible when I check the activity of someone else?

Tags: support, downvotes, voting, reputation-history, activity-tab

Can downvote-costs be seen in the activity tab of the profile?
If so it would be easy to validate revenge-downvotes, if you have a specific user in mind.

---

I changed the wording of the question, because it was assumed that this is about me seeking revenge for a possible revenge-downvote. While a possible revenge-dv was the reason why this came to my mind, it is not the intention of the question, rather the impulse to ask it. Glorfindel presented a perfect answer for my question. I would like to concentrate on the topic instead of people lecturing me that I just should not care about this.

Comment: Any effort to hunt down the suspected down voter is bound to end in drama. Just move on.

Comment: And no, you can't see downvote costs in other user's profiles. For exactly this reason.

Comment: @rene I do not want to hunt down a down voter. I want to know if it would be a revenge downvote and then would possibly check for moderator action. But my question is on the premise that this would make it easy to find revenge downvoters.

Comment: @yivi thanks for the info I will have followup question where I would like to know how to proceed in the specific case.

Comment: Moderators are not there to "reverse" alleged "revenge votes". If the user targets another user and an irregular voting pattern emerges, they will be caught by the reversal script. A single vote? **Just move on**.

Comment: It's [support]; you want to know how a part of the system works (or doesn't work, in this case).

Comment: @yivi On fourth thought ( I already think about it for some time) I will let it go and there will be no follow up question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Clearly not what the question is about.

Comment: @KameKaze clearly what this *real* question is about. If you were only interested in the "can we see downvotes cost" you wouldn't have mentioned the notion of hunting down a voter. That behaviour is discouraged.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Felix clearly you can not read my mind. I just framed the reason why the idea came to mind. My next step would have been to ask if a flag for this is warrented but I let it go. The answer of Glorfindel was everything I wanted know about with this Q.

Comment: Yeah, that's better @KamiKaze. There was no "assumption". Your question, as worded in the first revision, literally means hunting down someone. You opened their profile, with the clear goal of seeing if they had lost reputation at the same time of your downvote. That's what hunting down someone *means*.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier My definition of hunting down would involve a bit more effort then just a check of a single user without further actions. Given I considered a flag at this time, but I think if he does such things more often it will be visible at some point.

Comment: If it looks like revenge downvoting just flag it for mod investigation.... why do you want to investigate it myself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, they are not visible. As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161328/295232):

> You can't. Voting is private. Users need to be able to use their votes as they see fit based on the quality of the post they're voting on without worrying about confrontation. They have an option to leave a comment to explain their vote, but it's just that - an option. The only people that can see your votes are developers, and they have to work rather hard to get it. That's how it was designed.

I've had a few cases where I was rather certain of who (revenge) downvoted me (on a low-activity site); the best option is to just not engage and consider yourself a superior being :)